# Laravel 4 / Displaying posts with a category header (relationships pb)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

This is what I'd like to display on a course index page.

- Category 1
  -- Course 1
  -- Course 2
  -- Course 3
- Category 2
  -- Course 4
  -- Course 5
  -- Course 6

#### Course Table

```
Schema::create('courses', function($table) {      
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->text('content');
    $table->string('meta_title');
    $table->string('meta_description');
    $table->string('meta_keywords');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Category Table

```
Schema::create('categories', function($table) {   
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### Course Model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Category', 'id');
}
```

#### Category Model

```
public function courses() {
    return $this->hasMany('Course', 'id');
}
```

#### Course Controller

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $courses = Course::all();
    return View::make('site/eap/course/index', compact('categories', 'courses'));
}
```

#### Course Index View

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<h3>{{ $category->title }}</h3>
    @foreach($courses as $course)
    <h4><a href="{{{ $course->url() }}}">{{ $course->title }}</a></h4>
    <p>{{ $course->content }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This obviously returns all the courses under each category when I only want the courses of the corresponding category.

I tried everything possible but I think I'm missing the obvious. Where am I supposed to do the loop and where do I do it? In the controller, in the view, in both? How do we glue this together?

Answer (score 2):

Your course doesn't *have* a categoy, it *belongs* to one:

```
public function category ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
$categories = Category::with('courses')->get();
```

and in your view:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

    <h3>{{ $category->title }}</h3>

    @foreach($category->courses as $course)

        <h4><a href="{{ $course->url() }}">{{ $course->title }}</a></h4>
        <p>{{ $course->content }}</p>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```